# Set number of processes mpi in cmake project at qtcreator

Tags: c++, mpi, qt-creator, mpiexec

How can I set number of processes in qtcreator in a c++ MPI program?

I add `-n 4` into run arguments but the program was not run on 4 processes!!

Should I change `CMakeLists`?

Comment: What happens when you try `mpiexec -n 4 yourprog` at the command line ?

Comment: @High Performance Mark, I have no problem in command line! I want to run the program from qt-creator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In qtcreator menu :

projects -> build & run -> run -> add custom executable:

**Executable** : mpiexec

**Arguments** : -n 4 main

Note: 4 is **number of processes** and main is your **target name**.

Comment: is there a variable I can use within qt creator for the target name, like %{targetName}?